# Optional query params aqueduct

Tags: aqueduct

Went through the [documentation](https://aqueduct.io/docs/http/routing), couldn't find any.

How does one make an optional query param in aqueduct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By wrapping an argument in curly brackets:

```
@Operation.get()
Future<Response> getAllCities({@Bind.header('x-api-key') String apiKey}) async 
{}
```

This is documented here: http://aqueduct.io/docs/http/resource_controller/#optional-bindings

Comment: I think the entire section of the link you showed me (which I've been there a million times already), should be replaced by your first sentence. That's all that entire section needs to say about the optional bindings. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [optional binding documention](http://aqueduct.io/docs/http/resource_controller/#optional-bindings) gives examples how to use optional `query string parameters` or `headers`. But what about URL like this `//host.com/path/subpath`? Below the simple example:

```
// Dummy example class
class OptionalController extends ResourceController {
  @Operation.get()
  Future<Response> getItemsByDefault() => getItemsByCount(1);

  @Operation.get('count')
  Future<Response> getItemsByCount(@Bind.path('count') int count) async {
     return Response.ok(count);
  }
}
```